# How to create an archive of the folder using C++ in Visual Studio 2019, Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2019, libzip

I wanted to create a Windows Service which copies content of the folder into a created archive. I was suggested to use [libzip](https://libzip.org/) library for this purpouse. I've created this code, but now I do not know how to compile and link it properly. I am not using CMake for the project building in Visual Studio.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <zip.h>

constexpr auto directory = "C:/.../Directory/";
constexpr auto archPath = "C:/.../arch.zip";

int Archive(const std::filesystem::path& Directory, const std::filesystem::path& Archive) {
    int error = 0;
    zip* arch = zip_open(Archive.string().c_str(), ZIP_CREATE, &error);
    if (arch == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("Unable to open the archive.");


    for (const auto& file : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(Directory)) {
        const std::string filePath = file.path().string();
        const std::string nameInArchive = file.path().filename().string();

        auto* source = zip_source_file(arch, item.path().string().c_str(), 0, 0);
        if (source == nullptr)
            throw std::runtime_error("Error with creating source buffer.");

        auto result = zip_file_add(arch, nameInArchive.c_str(), source, ZIP_FL_OVERWRITE);
        if (result < 0)
           throw std::runtime_error("Unable to add file '" + filePath + "' to the archive.");
    }

    zip_close(arch);
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    std::filesystem::path Directory(directory);
    std::filesystem::path ArchiveLocation(archPath);

    Archive(Directory, ArchiveLocation);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, it's needed to install libzip package. Easiest way is to install it through the NuGet manager in Visual Studio. Go to `Project -> Manage NuGet Packages`. Select `Browse` tab and search for libzip and click `install`.
2. After the package is installed, you need to specify libraries location to the linker. It can be done so: `Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input.` Select `Additional Dependencies` on the right. Now you need to add path to the library. NuGet packages are usually installed in `C:\Users\...\.nuget\packages`. You need to add complete path to the library in double quotes. In my case, it is `"C:\Users\...\.nuget\packages\libzip\1.1.2.7\build\native\lib\Win32\v140\Debug\zip.lib"`.
3. Now program should compile and link. Upon launch, you may face errors, such as `zip.dll` or `zlibd.dll` is missing. For first, copy the zip.dll from `libzip.redist` package near to the program executable. For second, install zlib from the NuGet

Comment: Git already does a good job of archiving. Just set up a daemon or service and run it in the directory of interest at intervals.